# CountingClicker() takes no arguments - Python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-3.6

I can't do this exercise of the Joel Grus Books's, because does not present none clicker

`class CountingClicker: def _init_ (self, count = 0): self.count = count`

clicker1 = CountingClicker()
clicker2 = CountingClicker(count=100)

`TypeError     Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16988\1496624537.py in <module> 1 clicker1 = CountingClicker() ----> 2 clicker2 = CountingClicker(count=100)`

TypeError: CountingClicker() takes no arguments

I need to view the score

Answer (score 0):

you are not doint correctly constructor structure.you have a suntax error with Dash ( _ )
Try this instead of single dash.

```
class CountingClicker: def __init__ (self, count = 0): self.count = count
```

[image]